# How to get date automatically through a button

Tags: android, date, android-studio, automatic-storage

I want to know How to retrive date automatically by an Android app in Android Studio through a button.

Comment: In what format would you like the date though? Date object? String?

Answer (score 1):

In your onClick button listener method add:

```
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

```
   yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Create Date Object
                Date today = new Date();

                //Convert to calendar Object
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(today);

                int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                int weekOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                int weekOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
              }
        });
```

Comment: i want to know whether this needs to be included in main_activity.java